# Cant send cookie at res when user using Safari/iOS

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, safari

With a web server build with Node.js and Express.js
I'm attaching the cookies at the response

```
res.cookie('token', token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + sixMonths),
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'none',
    signed: true,
  });
```

When a user uses chrome or mozilla everything works at expected, but on safari getting an auth error because can't handle cross-over cookies, any solution?

solve express cookie problem

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're setting `sameSite: 'none'`, so you're telling your session you're going to work with crossed domains. To make this work, add the value `sameSite: true`

Comment: is possible to put sameSite true? didnt know that... Any way cant send request even from chrome now with sameSite: true